# active class for external navigation in jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I needed extarnal navigation for my jquery ui tabs.
I created links:

```
 <a href="#fragment-1" id="pin1">
```

and add js code:

```
$("#pin1").click(function() {$("#tabs").tabs( "select" , 0 );});
$("#pin2").click(function() {$("#tabs").tabs( "select" , 1 );});
```

Unfortunately now the links don't have active class. Is it possible to make it work like is in default tabs navigation?

Comment: what do you mean by "active class"?

Comment: "active" class for current tab so it can be styled different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/4wQVD/3/

Comment: yes, but the question is how to add "active" class for "pin 1" or "pin 2" when its clicked?